# Extract fixed length string between two numbers

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I have this number: `003859389453604802410207622210986832370060`. In this instance, I need to extract `07622210986832` which comes before `02` and ends with `37`.

In the real world, `07622210986832` is always 14 digits, and will always start with `02` and end with `37` BUT it could appear at any point in a string that is of random length - all we know is that the number will be there somewhere.

I'm currently using the formula:

```
 =IF(LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "02(.*)37")))=14,
```

However, you will notice in the number sample there is another `02` - "024102".
This is causing an issue.

What I really want to happen is:

- Lookup `02`
- Find the string of 14 numbers and if number 15 is `3` and 16 is `7` (37), that is the number we need.
- If you find another `02` number with a 14 digit string and the next two numbers are not `37` - ignore.

Comment: I've not tried Excel's regex dialect so it might not support this, but try turning `"02(.*)37"` into `"02(.{12})37"` to lock down that it must be exactly 12 characters there, rather than the asterisk which means "as many as possible".  That will still have a chance that there's an "02" followed by a "37" twelve digits away and is not the one you want, but if you have a pattern like `0000200000200000370000370000` and they happen to be two compatible overlapping possibilities, how would you resolve that?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - That's a good point and i'm hoping that your example of overlapping possibilities cannot and will not happen. I tried your {14} suggestion and it worked like a charm. Thank-you very much. Think it's a case of worry about the overlapping issue if it happens :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pattern `02(\d{14})37`, it will extract a sequence of 14 digits preceded by `02` and followed by `37`.

Comment: Correct answer, assuming OP uses GS (which he probably does)

Comment: @RobertBaron. Please could you advise what the \d does?

Comment: @manc_stu - `\d` represents any digit. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/Dd1KDn/1/) for testing any GS regular expression.

Comment: @RobertBaron WOW! what a great website!! :) Can't thank-you enough for putting me in touch with this. In two minutes already found that i can do 02(\d{2,14})37 for example for string between 2 and 14 digits. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Guys one last question....what's wrong with this? =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT((A2:A&"")+(B2:B&"")+(C2:C&"")), "02(\d{14})37")

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT({A2:A,B2:B,C2:C}), "02(\d{14})37"))
```

if you want to smash it into 1 column then:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT({A2:A,B2:B,C2:C}), 
 "02(\d{14})37")),,999^99))))
```

Comment: Great answer @player0, but if there is no value in columns B or C it displays #N/A #N/A. How do i remove these?

Comment: I did that and it returned just one #N/A. Before it would display the required string, plus #N/A #N/A

Comment: Sure,https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c-rlOtGxHAZ0nGI3gIAIyyjJm7vnJmFH5sW-Y2Si0WE/edit?usp=sharing